# What is special about the fifth element?

Tags: r

Consider the R following code:

```
x = seq(0,.6,by=0.2)
stopifnot( x == c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6)) # does not stop

x = seq(0,.8,by=0.2)
stopifnot( x == c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8)) # stops
```

Why aren't x and c(...) equivalent in the second case?

Comment: The fifth element is (spoiler) actually a woman.

Comment: @RichieCotton: Would it be correct to use `all.equal`instead of `==`?

Comment: Yes. Or possibly `isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))`, depending upon what you are doing.

Comment: @RichieCotton: Thanks man.